# Is this usage of python tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile secure?

Tags: python, file, temporary-files

Is this usage of Python tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile secure (i.e. devoid security issues of deprecated tempfile.mktemp)?

```
def mktemp2():
    """Create and close an empty temporary file.
    Return the temporary filename"""
    tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    tfilename = tf.name
    tf.close()
    return tfilename

outfilename = mktemp2()
subprocess.call(['program_name','-o',outfilename])
```

What I need to run external command that requires output file name as one of the arguments. It overwrites the outfilename if that exists without warnings. I want to use temporary file as I just need to read its content, I don't need it later.

Comment: That's totally correct.  Indeed, it's almost literally the code provided in the library documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mktemp.  Since you've copied and pasted from the documentation, what are you asking?  Why ask if you copied and pasted correctly?

Comment: Hmm, you're right it is there in the docs, but the sentence from the docs "mktemp() usage can be replaced easily with NamedTemporaryFile(), passing it the delete=False parameter" does not say explicitly that the "replacement" is safe (but yes, I would guess that it's what it is supposed to mean)... It's security issue, so I decided to double ask. And another answer to my question from gnibbler says it is indeed unsafe, so there is some uncertainty about this...

Answer (score 4):

Totally unsafe. There is an opportunity for an attacker to create the file with whatever permissions they like (or a symlink) with that name between when it is deleted and opened by the subprocess

If you can instead create the file in a directory other than /tmp that is owned and onnly read/writeable by your process, you don't need to concern yourself with the security of the file as anything in the directory is protected

Comment: And what about using outfilename = tempfile.mkstemp()[1] instead of my mktemp2 function?